Power Automate/Apps Connections unable to set Choose a Gateway
When using the current version of https://make.powerautomate.com or https://make.powerapps.com and we try to set a connection gateway, the save button stays greyed out and we are unable to set the gateway:

I reviewed the permissions and ownership but have not been able to get it to work. I have also verified these are in the same regions. I need some guidance on how to address this issue.

Usually when that button is greyed out, I found that making a small change to the 'Display name' input solves the problem and the save button works.
Something like adding a space/character and removing the space/character does the job.

I edited the name and selected the gateway and it worked. The save button enabled after this. That screen really needs some work. Thanks for the suggestion. Very helpful
